# Python Regex not extracting function name from line

Tags: python, regex

I have: 
function names in various c files in the following format:

```
void function0__ROM(void) {
     code for the function 
     }
void function1__ROM(void) {
     code for the function
     }
```

I wrote a Regex in python to extract function names, but somehow it is not working.

Following is my Regex:

```
match= re.search("\n\s*?(void|BYTE|WORD|bit)(\s*?\*\s*?)?\s+?)?\s+\?( " +func.name[l:]+ ")(__ROM)?\s*?\(.*?\)s*?[{]".file)
```

I am new to python, after a lot of study wrote this Regex, but somehow it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r"\s*(void|BYTE|WORD|bit)\s+"+func.name[1:]+"__ROM\s*\([^\)]*\)\s*{?\s*"
```

- one of words
- function name
- bracket
- everything what is not bracket
- ) spaces and possible {

Comment: The regex works most of the time. but for lines such as below: WORD function0__ROM(WORD time) { it is failing

Comment: I added \s* at the end of the regex (possible spaces at the end of line). Let me know if it is ok.

Comment: Are you sure that func.name[1:] contains "function0" ?

Comment: sorry but I tried it and it works for me

>>> a="WORD function0__ROM(WORD time) {"

>>> match = re.search(r"\s*(void|BYTE|WORD|bit)\s+function0__ROM\s*\([^\)]*\)\s*{?\s*",a)

>>> print match.group(0)
'WORD function0__ROM(WORD time) {'